# numpy array - use np.concatenate or np.insert to prepend and append rows of zeros to ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, concatenation

I am fairly new to numpy and I very well may be asking a stupid question, so I apologize in advance if this not a good question or if the question needs more clarifications.

**The task**

For example, I have an image represented as an ndarray of size (10,20,3) and I am trying to change the size of the array to (12,20,3) by inserting 1px at the beginning and at the end of the image. Essentially, I am trying to achieve image resize with padding only on the top and bottom of the image.

This is basically what I am trying to achieve, represented with arrays of smaller dimensions.

**Original array**

```
[ [[255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]]

 [[255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]]]
```

**Modified array**

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]]

 [[255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]]

 [[255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]]]
```

My plan is to use numpy.concatenate using the following steps.

#1 Create an array of 0's with this dimension (1,4,3)

#2 Concatenate the original array to the array from step 1. This will create a new array like this

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]]

 [[255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]]

 [[255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]
  [255. 255. 255.]]]
```

#3 Use the array from step 1 and append it to the array that was created in part 2 and this will finally give me the result I want.

However, I also wonder if there is a way to use numpy.insert and just insert (1,4,3) to the beginning and end of the array without complicating this with concatenate. I would appreciate any input on this.

Comment: you can concatenate your zeros (z) 255 array (mid) and the 2nd zero at once .... np.concatenate((z, mid, z)) .... where z.shape, mid.shape, z.shape  ... ((1, 5, 5), (2, 5, 5), (1, 5, 5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy.concatenate`, you can create a zero array to concatenate on either side.

```
zs = np.zeros((1,) + arr.shape[1:])
np.concatenate((zs, arr, zs))
```

Another option - create a zero array of the new size, and set the interior to be your original array.

```
padded_arr = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]+2,) + arr.shape[1:])
padded_arr[1:-1, ...] = arr
```

Lastly you can achieve this with [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy.pad), specifying a pad width for each axis.

```
np.pad(arr, ((1,), (0,), (0,)), 'constant')
```